# Vite failes to install vue-select-3 in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vite, laravel-10

I am trying to install `vue-select-3` in a `Laravel-10` project which uses `vite` and `vue-3`.

I installed `npm i vue-select-3` from `npm` and successfully imported the scss

```
@import "vue-select-3/src/scss/vue-select.scss";
```

Problems arose as I added the js plugin

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import vSelect from 'vue-select-3'

const app = createApp({});
app.component("v-select", Select);
app.mount('#app');
```

The error message it brings is:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve entry for package "vue-select-3". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

Any help is welcome.